# How to make clangd work with single-header library that uses an implementation macro

Tags: clangd

I have a CMake project that generates a compile_commands.json database, which is used by clangd to provide completion and errors for me. This worked well until I brought in `stb_image.h` (a single-header image loading library) to my project. stb_image uses the standard macro-based approach to define its symbols, which looks like this:

```
#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "stb_image.h"
```

In a source file. Now I've done something also quite common and standard in creating a separate source file `stb_impl.cc` just for these two lines hoping the resulting compilation unit would be picked up by CMake and put in compile_commands.json to avoid any problems with clangd not seeing the right info. But even so I'm stuck with this error:

[image]

Which only seems to occur with the macro definition, not with the include statement by itself. This is VS Code btw.

I have heard of the workaround of adding a post-process tool like compdb to explicitly add header files to compile_commands.json, but compdb isn't actively developed anymore and I'd rather not add any potential abandonware to my project. And I wonder if that would even fix my problem in the first place. Is there a better solution to be had here?

If anyone could help me to better understand what's going on here I would be grateful.

Edit: This is the clangd log when opening the file (lol_engine.cc in my project):

```
I[16:36:22.231] clangd version 17.0.4
I[16:36:22.231] Features: windows
I[16:36:22.231] PID: 4008
I[16:36:22.231] Working directory: c:\Users\reddd\source\oceanlight
I[16:36:22.231] argv[0]: C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin\clangd.exe
I[16:36:22.231] argv[1]: -header-insertion=never
I[16:36:22.231] argv[2]: --log=verbose
V[16:36:22.237] User config file is C:\Users\reddd\AppData\Local\clangd\config.yaml
I[16:36:22.237] Starting LSP over stdin/stdout
V[16:36:22.238] <<< {"id":0,"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"initialize","params":{"capabilities":{"general":{"markdown":{"parser":"marked","version":"1.1.0"},"positionEncodings":["utf-16"],"regularExpressions":{"engine":"ECMAScript","version":"ES2020"},"staleRequestSupport":{"cancel":true,"retryOnContentModified":["textDocument/semanticTokens/full","textDocument/semanticTokens/range","textDocument/semanticTokens/full/delta"]}},"notebookDocument":{"synchronization":{"dynamicRegistration":true,"executionSummarySupport":true}},"textDocument":{"callHierarchy":{"dynamicRegistration":true},"codeAction":{"codeActionLiteralSupport":{"codeActionKind":{"valueSet":["","quickfix","refactor","refactor.extract","refactor.inline","refactor.rewrite","source","source.organizeImports"]}},"dataSupport":true,"disabledSupport":true,"dynamicRegistration":true,"honorsChangeAnnotations":false,"isPreferredSupport":true,"resolveSupport":{"properties":["edit"]}},"codeLens":{"dynamicRegistration":true},"colorProvider":{"dynamicRegistration":true},"completion":{"completionItem":{"commitCharactersSupport":true,"deprecatedSupport":true,"documentationFormat":["markdown","plaintext"],"insertReplaceSupport":true,"insertTextModeSupport":{"valueSet":[1,2]},"labelDetailsSupport":true,"preselectSupport":true,"resolveSupport":{"properties":["documentation","detail","additionalTextEdits"]},"snippetSupport":true,"tagSupport":{"valueSet":[1]}},"completionItemKind":{"valueSet":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25]},"completionList":{"itemDefaults":["commitCharacters","editRange","insertTextFormat","insertTextMode"]},"contextSupport":true,"dynamicRegistration":true,"editsNearCursor":true,"insertTextMode":2},"declaration":{"dynamicRegistration":true,"linkSupport":true},"definition":{"dynamicRegistration":true,"linkSupport":true},"diagnostic":{"dynamicRegistration":true,"relatedDocumentSupport":false},"documentHighlight":{"dynamicRegistration":true},"documentLink":{"dynamicRegistration":true,"tooltipSupport":true},"documentSymbol":{"dynamicRegistration":true,"hierarchicalDocumentSymbolSupport":true,"labelSupport":true,"symbolKind":{"valueSet":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26]},"tagSupport":{"valueSet":[1]}},"foldingRange":{"dynamicRegistration":true,"foldingRange":{"collapsedText":false},"foldingRangeKind":{"valueSet":["comment","imports","region"]},"lineFoldingOnly":true,"rangeLimit":5000},"formatting":{"dynamicRegistration":true},"hover":{"contentFormat":["markdown","plaintext"],"dynamicRegistration":true},"implementation":{"dynamicRegistration":true,"linkSupport":true},"inlayHint":{"dynamicRegistration":true,"resolveSupport":{"properties":["tooltip","textEdits","label.tooltip","label.location","label.command"]}},"inlineValue":{"dynamicRegistration":true},"linkedEditingRange":{"dynamicRegistration":true},"onTypeFormatting":{"dynamicRegistration":true},"publishDiagnostics":{"codeDescriptionSupport":true,"dataSupport":true,"relatedInformation":true,"tagSupport":{"valueSet":[1,2]},"versionSupport":false},"rangeFormatting":{"dynamicRegistration":true},"references":{"dynamicRegistration":true},"rename":{"dynamicRegistration":true,"honorsChangeAnnotations":true,"prepareSupport":true,"prepareSupportDefaultBehavior":1},"selectionRange":{"dynamicRegistration":true},"semanticTokens":{"augmentsSyntaxTokens":true,"dynamicRegistration":true,"formats":["relative"],"multilineTokenSupport":false,"overlappingTokenSupport":false,"requests":{"full":{"delta":true},"range":true},"serverCancelSupport":true,"tokenModifiers":["declaration","definition","readonly","static","deprecated","abstract","async","modification","documentation","defaultLibrary"],"tokenTypes":["namespace","type","class","enum","interface","struct","typeParameter","parameter","variable","property","enumMember","event","function","method","macro","keyword","modifier","comment","string","number","regexp","operator","decorator"]},"signatureHelp":{"contextSupport":true,"dynamicRegistration":true,"signatureInformation":{"activeParameterSupport":true,"documentationFormat":["markdown","plaintext"],"parameterInformation":{"labelOffsetSupport":true}}},"synchronization":{"didSave":true,"dynamicRegistration":true,"willSave":true,"willSaveWaitUntil":true},"typeDefinition":{"dynamicRegistration":true,"linkSupport":true},"typeHierarchy":{"dynamicRegistration":true}},"window":{"showDocument":{"support":true},"showMessage":{"messageActionItem":{"additionalPropertiesSupport":true}},"workDoneProgress":true},"workspace":{"applyEdit":true,"codeLens":{"refreshSupport":true},"configuration":true,"diagnostics":{"refreshSupport":true},"didChangeConfiguration":{"dynamicRegistration":true},"didChangeWatchedFiles":{"dynamicRegistration":true,"relativePatternSupport":true},"executeCommand":{"dynamicRegistration":true},"fileOperations":{"didCreate":true,"didDelete":true,"didRename":true,"dynamicRegistration":true,"willCreate":true,"willDelete":true,"willRename":true},"inlayHint":{"refreshSupport":true},"inlineValue":{"refreshSupport":true},"semanticTokens":{"refreshSupport":true},"symbol":{"dynamicRegistration":true,"resolveSupport":{"properties":["location.range"]},"symbolKind":{"valueSet":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26]},"tagSupport":{"valueSet":[1]}},"workspaceEdit":{"changeAnnotationSupport":{"groupsOnLabel":true},"documentChanges":true,"failureHandling":"textOnlyTransactional","normalizesLineEndings":true,"resourceOperations":["create","rename","delete"]},"workspaceFolders":true}},"clientInfo":{"name":"Visual Studio Code - Insiders","version":"1.85.0-insider"},"initializationOptions":{"clangdFileStatus":true,"fallbackFlags":[]},"locale":"en-us","processId":1012,"rootPath":"c:\\Users\\reddd\\source\\oceanlight","rootUri":"file:///c%3A/Users/reddd/source/oceanlight","trace":"off","workspaceFolders":[{"name":"oceanlight","uri":"file:///c%3A/Users/reddd/source/oceanlight"}]}}

I[16:36:22.238] <-- initialize(0)
I[16:36:22.240] --> reply:initialize(0) 1 ms
V[16:36:22.240] >>> {"id":0,"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":{"capabilities":{"astProvider":true,"callHierarchyProvider":true,"clangdInlayHintsProvider":true,"codeActionProvider":{"codeActionKinds":["quickfix","refactor","info"]},"compilationDatabase":{"automaticReload":true},"completionProvider":{"resolveProvider":false,"triggerCharacters":[".","<",">",":","\"","/","*"]},"declarationProvider":true,"definitionProvider":true,"documentFormattingProvider":true,"documentHighlightProvider":true,"documentLinkProvider":{"resolveProvider":false},"documentOnTypeFormattingProvider":{"firstTriggerCharacter":"\n","moreTriggerCharacter":[]},"documentRangeFormattingProvider":true,"documentSymbolProvider":true,"executeCommandProvider":{"commands":["clangd.applyFix","clangd.applyTweak"]},"foldingRangeProvider":true,"hoverProvider":true,"implementationProvider":true,"inactiveRegionsProvider":true,"inlayHintProvider":true,"memoryUsageProvider":true,"referencesProvider":true,"renameProvider":{"prepareProvider":true},"selectionRangeProvider":true,"semanticTokensProvider":{"full":{"delta":true},"legend":{"tokenModifiers":["declaration","definition","deprecated","deduced","readonly","static","abstract","virtual","dependentName","defaultLibrary","usedAsMutableReference","usedAsMutablePointer","constructorOrDestructor","userDefined","functionScope","classScope","fileScope","globalScope"],"tokenTypes":["variable","variable","parameter","function","method","function","property","variable","class","interface","enum","enumMember","type","type","unknown","namespace","typeParameter","concept","type","macro","modifier","operator","bracket","label","comment"]},"range":false},"signatureHelpProvider":{"triggerCharacters":["(",")","{","}","<",">",","]},"standardTypeHierarchyProvider":true,"textDocumentSync":{"change":2,"openClose":true,"save":true},"typeDefinitionProvider":true,"typeHierarchyProvider":true,"workspaceSymbolProvider":true},"serverInfo":{"name":"clangd","version":"clangd version 17.0.4 windows x86_64-pc-windows-msvc"}}}

V[16:36:22.242] <<< {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"initialized","params":{}}

I[16:36:22.242] <-- initialized
I[16:36:22.247] <-- textDocument/didOpen
I[16:36:22.249] Loaded compilation database from c:\Users\reddd\source\oceanlight\build/compile_commands.json
I[16:36:22.253] Loaded compilation database from C:\Users\reddd\source\oceanlight\build\compile_commands.json
I[16:36:22.255] --> window/workDoneProgress/create(0)
V[16:36:22.255] >>> {"id":0,"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"window/workDoneProgress/create","params":{"token":"backgroundIndexProgress"}}

I[16:36:22.255] Enqueueing 12 commands for indexing
V[16:36:22.256] <<< {"id":0,"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":null}

I[16:36:22.256] <-- reply(0)
I[16:36:22.256] --> $/progress
V[16:36:22.256] >>> {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"$/progress","params":{"token":"backgroundIndexProgress","value":{"kind":"begin","percentage":0,"title":"indexing"}}}

I[16:36:22.256] --> $/progress
V[16:36:22.256] >>> {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"$/progress","params":{"token":"backgroundIndexProgress","value":{"kind":"report","message":"0/1","percentage":0}}}

I[16:36:22.259] --> textDocument/clangd.fileStatus
V[16:36:22.259] >>> {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"textDocument/clangd.fileStatus","params":{"state":"parsing includes, running Update","uri":"file:///c:/Users/reddd/source/oceanlight/liboceanlight/src/lol_engine.cc"}}

V[16:36:22.259] Building first preamble for c:\Users\reddd\source\oceanlight\liboceanlight\src\lol_engine.cc version 1
V[16:36:22.273] <<< {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"$/setTrace","params":{"value":"off"}}

I[16:36:22.273] <-- $/setTrace
I[16:36:22.273] unhandled notification $/setTrace
V[16:36:22.455] BackgroundIndex: building version 1 after loading index from disk
V[16:36:22.649] BackgroundIndex: serving version 1 (42361812 bytes)
I[16:36:22.704] --> $/progress
V[16:36:22.704] >>> {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"$/progress","params":{"token":"backgroundIndexProgress","value":{"kind":"report","message":"0/2","percentage":0}}}

I[16:36:22.704] --> $/progress
V[16:36:22.704] >>> {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"$/progress","params":{"token":"backgroundIndexProgress","value":{"kind":"report","message":"0/2","percentage":0}}}

I[16:36:22.705] --> $/progress
V[16:36:22.705] >>> {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"$/progress","params":{"token":"backgroundIndexProgress","value":{"kind":"report","message":"1/2","percentage":50}}}

V[16:36:22.705] Indexing C:\Users\reddd\source\oceanlight\liboceanlight\src\lol_engine.cc (digest:=87447B9F074A07B8)
V[16:36:22.893] <<< {"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"textDocument/documentLink","params":{"textDocument":{"uri":"file:///c%3A/Users/reddd/source/oceanlight/liboceanlight/src/lol_engine.cc"}}}

I[16:36:22.893] <-- textDocument/documentLink(1)
V[16:36:23.108] <<< {"id":2,"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"textDocument/codeAction","params":{"context":{"diagnostics":[],"triggerKind":2},"range":{"end":{"character":17,"line":2},"start":{"character":17,"line":2}},"textDocument":{"uri":"file:///c%3A/Users/reddd/source/oceanlight/liboceanlight/src/lol_engine.cc"}}}

I[16:36:23.108] <-- textDocument/codeAction(2)
V[16:36:23.164] <<< {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"$/setTrace","params":{"value":"off"}}

I[16:36:23.164] <-- $/setTrace
I[16:36:23.164] unhandled notification $/setTrace
V[16:36:23.219] <<< {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"$/setTrace","params":{"value":"off"}}

I[16:36:23.219] <-- $/setTrace
I[16:36:23.219] unhandled notification $/setTrace
V[16:36:23.237] <<< {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"$/cancelRequest","params":{"id":2}}

I[16:36:23.237] <-- $/cancelRequest
V[16:36:23.264] <<< {"id":3,"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"textDocument/codeAction","params":{"context":{"diagnostics":[],"triggerKind":2},"range":{"end":{"character":17,"line":2},"start":{"character":17,"line":2}},"textDocument":{"uri":"file:///c%3A/Users/reddd/source/oceanlight/liboceanlight/src/lol_engine.cc"}}}

I[16:36:23.264] <-- textDocument/codeAction(3)
V[16:36:23.266] <<< {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"$/cancelRequest","params":{"id":3}}

I[16:36:23.266] <-- $/cancelRequest
V[16:36:23.281] <<< {"id":4,"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"textDocument/codeAction","params":{"context":{"diagnostics":[],"triggerKind":2},"range":{"end":{"character":17,"line":2},"start":{"character":17,"line":2}},"textDocument":{"uri":"file:///c%3A/Users/reddd/source/oceanlight/liboceanlight/src/lol_engine.cc"}}}

I[16:36:23.281] <-- textDocument/codeAction(4)
V[16:36:23.375] <<< {"id":5,"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"textDocument/foldingRange","params":{"textDocument":{"uri":"file:///c%3A/Users/reddd/source/oceanlight/liboceanlight/src/lol_engine.cc"}}}

I[16:36:23.375] <-- textDocument/foldingRange(5)
I[16:36:23.376] --> reply:textDocument/foldingRange(5) 1 ms

V[16:36:23.381] <<< {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"$/setTrace","params":{"value":"off"}}

I[16:36:23.381] <-- $/setTrace
I[16:36:23.381] unhandled notification $/setTrace
V[16:36:23.392] <<< {"id":6,"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"textDocument/semanticTokens/full","params":{"textDocument":{"uri":"file:///c%3A/Users/reddd/source/oceanlight/liboceanlight/src/lol_engine.cc"}}}

I[16:36:23.392] <-- textDocument/semanticTokens/full(6)
V[16:36:23.395] <<< {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"$/setTrace","params":{"value":"off"}}

I[16:36:23.395] <-- $/setTrace
I[16:36:23.395] unhandled notification $/setTrace
V[16:36:23.409] <<< {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"$/cancelRequest","params":{"id":1}}

I[16:36:23.409] <-- $/cancelRequest
V[16:36:23.411] <<< {"id":7,"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"textDocument/documentLink","params":{"textDocument":{"uri":"file:///c%3A/Users/reddd/source/oceanlight/liboceanlight/src/lol_engine.cc"}}}

I[16:36:23.411] <-- textDocument/documentLink(7)
V[16:36:23.950] <<< {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"$/cancelRequest","params":{"id":4}}

I[16:36:23.950] <-- $/cancelRequest
V[16:36:23.962] <<< {"id":8,"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"textDocument/codeAction","params":{"context":{"diagnostics":[],"triggerKind":2},"range":{"end":{"character":17,"line":2},"start":{"character":17,"line":2}},"textDocument":{"uri":"file:///c%3A/Users/reddd/source/oceanlight/liboceanlight/src/lol_engine.cc"}}}

I[16:36:23.962] <-- textDocument/codeAction(8)
V[16:36:23.963] <<< {"id":9,"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"textDocument/documentSymbol","params":{"textDocument":{"uri":"file:///c%3A/Users/reddd/source/oceanlight/liboceanlight/src/lol_engine.cc"}}}

I[16:36:23.963] <-- textDocument/documentSymbol(9)
I[16:36:24.108] Built preamble of size 24013120 for file c:\Users\reddd\source\oceanlight\liboceanlight\src\lol_engine.cc version 1 in 1.85 seconds
I[16:36:24.109] --> workspace/semanticTokens/refresh(1)
V[16:36:24.109] >>> {"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"workspace/semanticTokens/refresh","params":null}

I[16:36:24.109] --> textDocument/clangd.fileStatus
I[16:36:24.109] Indexing c++20 standard library in the context of c:\Users\reddd\source\oceanlight\liboceanlight\src\lol_engine.cc
V[16:36:24.109] >>> {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"textDocument/clangd.fileStatus","params":{"state":"parsing includes, running Build AST","uri":"file:///c:/Users/reddd/source/oceanlight/liboceanlight/src/lol_engine.cc"}}

V[16:36:24.220] Dropped diagnostic: C:\Users\reddd\source\oceanlight\build\liboceanlight\external\stb\src\stb_image.h: unused function 'stbi__cpuid3'
V[16:36:24.220] Dropped diagnostic: C:\Users\reddd\source\oceanlight\build\liboceanlight\external\stb\src\stb_image.h: unused function 'stbi__sse2_available'
V[16:36:24.220] Dropped diagnostic: C:\Users\reddd\source\oceanlight\build\liboceanlight\external\stb\src\stb_image.h: unused function 'stbi__refill_buffer'
V[16:36:24.220] Dropped diagnostic: C:\Users\reddd\source\oceanlight\build\liboceanlight\external\stb\src\stb_image.h: unused function 'stbi__start_mem'
V[16:36:24.220] Dropped diagnostic: C:\Users\reddd\source\oceanlight\build\liboceanlight\external\stb\src\stb_image.h: unused function 'stbi__start_callbacks'
V[16:36:24.220] Dropped diagnostic: C:\Users\reddd\source\oceanlight\build\liboceanlight\external\stb\src\stb_image.h: unused function 'stbi__start_file'
V[16:36:24.220] Dropped diagnostic: C:\Users\reddd\source\oceanlight\build\liboceanlight\external\stb\src\stb_image.h: unused function 'stbi__rewind'
V[16:36:24.220] Dropped diagnostic: C:\Users\reddd\source\oceanlight\build\liboceanlight\external\stb\src\stb_image.h: unused function 'stbi__jpeg_test'
V[16:36:24.220] Dropped diagnostic: C:\Users\reddd\source\oceanlight\build\liboceanlight\external\stb\src\stb_image.h: unused function 'stbi__jpeg_load'
V[16:36:24.220] Dropped diagnostic: C:\Users\reddd\source\oceanlight\build\liboceanlight\external\stb\src\stb_image.h: unused function 'stbi__jpeg_info'
V[16:36:24.220] Dropped diagnostic: C:\Users\reddd\source\oceanlight\build\liboceanlight\external\stb\src\stb_image.h: unused function 'stbi__png_test'
V[16:36:24.220] Dropped diagnostic: C:\Users\reddd\source\oceanlight\build\liboceanlight\external\stb\src\stb_image.h: unused function 'stbi__png_load'
V[16:36:24.220] Dropped diagnostic: C:\Users\reddd\source\oceanlight\build\liboceanlight\external\stb\src\stb_image.h: unused function 'stbi__png_info'
V[16:36:24.220] Dropped diagnostic: C:\Users\reddd\source\oceanlight\build\liboceanlight\external\stb\src\stb_image.h: unused function 'stbi__png_is16'
V[16:36:24.220] Dropped diagnostic: C:\Users\reddd\source\oceanlight\build\liboceanlight\external\stb\src\stb_image.h: unused function 'stbi__bmp_test'
V[16:36:24.220] Dropped diagnostic: C:\Users\reddd\source\oceanlight\build\liboceanlight\external\stb\src\stb_image.h: unused function 'stbi__bmp_load'
V[16:36:24.220] Dropped diagnostic: C:\Users\reddd\source\oceanlight\build\liboceanlight\external\stb\src\stb_image.h: unused function 'stbi__bmp_info'
V[16:36:24.220] Dropped diagnostic: C:\Users\reddd\source\oceanlight\build\liboceanlight\external\stb\src\stb_image.h: unused function 'stbi__tga_test'
V[16:36:24.220] Dropped diagnostic: C:\Users\reddd\source\oceanlight\build\liboceanlight\external\stb\src\stb_image.h: unused function 'stbi__tga_load'
V[16:36:24.231] indexed file AST for c:\Users\reddd\source\oceanlight\liboceanlight\src\lol_engine.cc version 1:
  symbol slab: 9 symbols, 6312 bytes
  ref slab: 167 symbols, 274 refs, 17488 bytes
  relations slab: 0 relations, 24 bytes
V[16:36:24.231] Build dynamic index for main-file symbols with estimated memory usage of 41824 bytes
I[16:36:24.231] --> textDocument/publishDiagnostics
V[16:36:24.231] >>> {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"textDocument/publishDiagnostics","params":{"diagnostics":[{"code":"fatal_too_many_errors","message":"Too many errors emitted, stopping now","range":{"end":{"character":0,"line":0},"start":{"character":0,"line":0}},"relatedInformation":[],"severity":1,"source":"clang"}],"uri":"file:///c:/Users/reddd/source/oceanlight/liboceanlight/src/lol_engine.cc","version":1}}

I[16:36:24.232] --> reply:textDocument/documentLink(1) 1339 ms, error: Task was cancelled.
V[16:36:24.232] >>> {"error":{"code":-32800,"message":"Request cancelled"},"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}

I[16:36:24.232] --> reply:textDocument/codeAction(2) 1123 ms, error: Task was cancelled.
V[16:36:24.232] >>> {"error":{"code":-32800,"message":"Request cancelled"},"id":2,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}

I[16:36:24.232] --> reply:textDocument/codeAction(3) 968 ms, error: Task was cancelled.
V[16:36:24.232] >>> {"error":{"code":-32800,"message":"Request cancelled"},"id":3,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}

I[16:36:24.232] --> reply:textDocument/codeAction(4) 951 ms, error: Task was cancelled.
V[16:36:24.232] >>> {"error":{"code":-32800,"message":"Request cancelled"},"id":4,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}

V[16:36:24.232] ASTWorker running SemanticHighlights on version 1 of c:\Users\reddd\source\oceanlight\liboceanlight\src\lol_engine.cc
I[16:36:24.233] --> reply:textDocument/semanticTokens/full(6) 840 ms

V[16:36:26.418] Ignored diagnostic. C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\include\experimental/filesystem:28:2:The <experimental/filesystem> header providing std::experimental::filesystem is deprecated by Microsoft and will be REMOVED. It is superseded by the C++17 <filesystem> header providing std::filesystem. You can define _SILENCE_EXPERIMENTAL_FILESYSTEM_DEPRECATION_WARNING to suppress this error.
I[16:36:26.735] Indexed c++20 standard library (incomplete due to errors): 15048 symbols, 7655 filtered
V[16:36:26.859] Build dynamic index for header symbols with estimated memory usage of 26303316 bytes
```

My project structure looks like this:

```
tree /f
C:.
│   .clang-format
│   .clang-tidy
│   .gitignore
│   CMakeLists.txt
│   CONTRIBUTING.md
│   LICENSE
│   README.md
│
├───.vscode
│       settings.json
│
├───build
├───liboceanlight
│   │   CMakeLists.txt
│   │   config.h.in
│   │
│   ├───include
│   │   └───liboceanlight
│   │           lol_debug_messenger.hpp
│   │           lol_engine.hpp
│   │           lol_engine_init.hpp
│   │           lol_engine_shutdown.hpp
│   │           lol_glfw_callbacks.hpp
│   │           lol_utility.hpp
│   │           lol_version.hpp
│   │           lol_window.hpp
│   │
│   ├───shaders
│   │       fragment_shader.frag
│   │       vertex_shader.vert
│   │
│   ├───src
│   │       lol_debug_messenger.cc
│   │       lol_engine.cc
│   │       lol_engine_init.cc
│   │       lol_engine_shutdown.cc
│   │       lol_glfw_callbacks.cc
│   │       lol_utility.cc
│   │       lol_version.cc
│   │       lol_window.cc
│   │       stb_impl.cc
│   │
│   └───test
│           CMakeLists.txt
│           lol_utility_test.cc
│
└───oceanlight
    │   CMakeLists.txt
    │   config.h.in
    │
    ├───include
    │       args.hpp
    │
    ├───src
    │       args.cc
    │       oceanlight.cc
    │
    └───test
```

With CMake configured to a generate compile_commands.json for clangd to parse.

I have also tried defining `STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION` in a local `.clangd` file, but I still get the same diagnostic wherever stb_image.h is included.

I should also mention I do not get this problem when using neovim's LSP under WSL. Nor do I get it on VS Code under WSL.

Comment: It's hard to say anything without more information such as: (1) which file are you opening in the editor when you're getting the unexpected errors, and (2) what are the errors ("too many errors omitted, stopping now" is just something the compiler produces after it has produced a bunch of actual errors and given up). A complete [clangd log](https://clangd.llvm.org/troubleshooting#gathering-logs) would also be useful for diagnosis.

Comment: I've edited the post and added some extra details hopefully it helps.

Comment: "Too many errors emitted" is never the only error. You should have more error messages.

Comment: What's really odd is that the log really does show clangd sending just one diagnostic, and that diagnostic being "Too many errors emitted". I've never seen that before. One question though: does this error only occur in `stb_impl.cc`? If so, does it actually bother you? Or if it occurs in other files that include `stb_image.h`, can you show a log that shows you opening one of those other files?

Comment: It only occurs at the top of the file that's defining that macro STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION, without the macro the diagnostic goes away completely, but ofc then I don't get the implementations of those functions either :\ ... I've replaced the previous log of stb_impl.cc with a new one for a different file also defining the macro and including the header just as before. I tried to keep the relevant parts but had to cut some stuff out due to character limit.

Comment: The updated log shows the same thing, just the "too many errors" diagnostic and nothing else. Very strange. My only suggestion at this point is, if you're able to share enough code for someone else to reproduce the problem, to file an issue at https://github.com/clangd/clangd/issues for more in-depth investigation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so as it turns out, making a `.clangd` file with the following contents does indeed fix this for me:

```
CompileFlags:
  Add: -ferror-limit=0
```

I figured out that I was setting `-ferror-limit` to very large values instead of zero and I guess those values just weren't large enough.

I still don't know why this works, or how adding more errors makes the errors disappear, or where the errors go when they die, but this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't know compdb, but I mean, compile_commands.json is really just pretty boring json, just add an entry for a compile unit `stb_image.h` which copies the configuration from an appropriate existing entry, adjusts `"file"` to be the path to `stb_image.h`, adjusts `"output"` to be something like `"stb_image_temp.o"`, copies over the `"command"`, but appends a `-DSTB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION` to that.

You do that operation in a `add_custom_command`. It should be possible to piece that together in a single invocation of `jq`.